# What is the diffrecne between -mfloat-abi=softfp and -mfloat-abi=hard flags?

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, yocto

What is the difference between **-mfloat-abi=softfp** and **-mfloat-abi=hard**  cross compiler flags?

I am working on an embedded Linux project and below is some info that you might need to answer my question please.

Processor: I.MX6ULL,
Linux Kernel version: 4.19,
Programing Language: C,
Cross Compiler variant: arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 8.2.0,

Many thanks,

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Unfortunately, the answer in the link does not answer the OP's question: GCC 7.1.0 for ARM (I did not have 8.2.0 for testing) uses "hard" floating point numbers in both cases (so `-mfloat-abi=softfp` does not cause the compiler to use "soft" floating point).

Comment: @MartinRosenau *"so -mfloat-abi=softfp does not cause the compiler to use "soft" floating point"* Your answer below says the same thing as the link: that the calling convention stores floats in integer registers, but the float operations are still done on FPU.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Now I see it. However, when I log in with my account (I don't know if the order of answers depend on the log-in), the answers that only (implicitly) explain the difference between "soft" and "softfp" are shown first and the answers that explain the difference between "hard" and "softfp" are shown at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introduction if you are not familiar with assembly language**

A CPU (and compiled programs) works very differently from high-level programming languages like C, Java etc...

The most important difference in the context of your question is that a CPU can neither pass arguments nor return values in a function call. So if you have some function call `example(5, 6, 7)`, the compiler must store the values `5`, `6` and `7` somewhere and call the function `example()`. The function `example()` must know where the function arguments are stored.

The way how and where the function arguments are stored is called "calling convention".

If you use different "calling conventions" for different functions in your program and the compiler does not know about this, it is highly probable that the **wrong function arguments** are passed to a function.

One example: If you call a function with `_pascal` calling convention in old 16-bit Windows but the compiler "thinks" that the function has `_stdcall` calling convention, the program will perform `example(7, 6, 5)` instead of `example(5, 6, 7)`.

**The meanings of the `-mfloat-abi` flags**

Comparing the difference of the assembly code generated on GCC 7.1.0, I have the following understanding:

> `-mfloat-abi=hard`

The compiler stores the function arguments in the registers of the floating-point unit. (And it uses and requires a CPU with floating-point support, of course.)

> `-mfloat-abi=soft`

The compiler stores the function arguments in integer registers.

Instead of using floating-point functionality of the CPU, it calls functions that perform basic operations (e.g. adding two floating point numbers).

This allows you to run the program on a CPU without floating-point support if you have a library that perform the "basic operations" using multiple integer operations.

> `-mfloat-abi=softfp`

The compiler **uses** the floating-point unit, but it **stores** the function arguments in the integer registers.

This has the following consequences:

- Just like `-mfloat-abi=hard`, the program will only run on CPUs that have floating-point support because it uses the floating-point features of the CPU.
- The code is a bit slower and longer than `-mfloat-abi=hard`, but faster than `-mfloat-abi-soft`
- **You can mix** up code compiled with `-mfloat-abi=soft` and `-mfloat-abi=softfp`, but not with `-mfloat-abi=hard`.

You would typically use this if you have a pre-compiled function (library or object file) compiled with `-mfloat-abi=soft` and you want to use this in your project running on a CPU that supports floating-point.

**What happens if the wrong flag is used?**

As long as the entire code in your project (**) is compiled with the same flag (and your CPU has floating-point support), nothing happens.

(**) In this context, floating-point functions in shared libraries called by your program is also part of your project!

If a function compiled with `-msoft-abi=hard` calls a function compiled with `-msoft-abi=soft[fp]` or vice-versa, the called function will not interpret the function arguments correctly, just like the function `example()` in the Windows 16 example above.

Comment: very comprehensive. thanks